# Как реализовать обход массива несколькими потоками?

Tags: php, многопоточность, curl

Есть массив ссылок, по которому нужно пройтись и скачать каждый файл.Если прохожу его обычным curl, то выходит в среднем 200-300 секунд на скачивание всех файлов по ссылкам.
Как реализовать, чтобы код не ждал последовательно загрузки каждого файла по 1, а, например, качал сразу по 5-10 одновременно?Понимаю что это нужно делать через multi curl, но пока курю его и единственное что вменяемое смог найти это:

```
// создаем обработчики
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// устанавливаем опции
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

// добавляем обработчики
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$running = null;
// выполняем запросы
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running > 0);

// освободим ресурсы
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Но и в данном примере реализуется только 2 потока и то руками и руками же вбивается в каждый нужный url.Как реализовать данную многопоточность для массива с n значениями, чтобы multicurl для этого массива сразу же делал потоки по 10 одновременных скачиваний?Думал на счет цикла, но понять как это реализовать не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так циклом и создавайте

```
//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$urls = ['http://lxr.php.net/', 'http://www.php.net/'];
$handles = [];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  // создаем обработчики
  $ch = curl_init();
  $handles[] = $ch;
  // устанавливаем опции
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
}

$running = null;
// выполняем запросы
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running > 0);

// освободим ресурсы
foreach ($handles as $ch) {
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
  curl_close($ch);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
```